# How to center a wrapper-div and not the content

Tags: html, css, positioning

I want my page to always be centered in the browser without affecting the content( like align-text: center; does). I want to center my wrapper-div.. How do I do this?

Simplifed existing page:

```
<div id="wrapper">       
    <div id="header">
        Music Heaven
    </div>
    <div id="topmeny">             
    </div>
    <div id="menu">        
    </div>        
    <div id="content">                  
    </div>           
    <div id="bottom">
        SiteAdmin
    </div>
</div>
```

Entire fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EndQb/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
 #wrapper {
     width: ...
     margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

no need to set text-align

Comment: Actually, there is a need: it's the only way to get this to work in IE. You must then left align the text in elements contained within the wrapper.

Comment: This was true until IE6. On IE7+ text-align no longer needs. see http://jsfiddle.net/7zkZS/

Comment: Oh right. I was under the impression it was required for IE8 even. Thank you for telling me otherwise :-)

Comment: Why can't I add this to the `body` tag?

Answer (score 2):

Set your style something like for the wrapper div.

```
#wrapper {

width: 841px;
margin: 0 auto;
```

}

In this way the wrapper div will always be centered according to your screen width. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

you can set the margin property for the wrapper div like following in CSS

```
#wrapper { margin:20px auto }
```