# How to center webpage in HTML5 properly

Tags: css, html

From what I find on this site, webpages are typically centered using an overall `<div>` called `#wrapper` that has auto margins, or some other clever attribute. For example, [in this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701054/html-css-how-to-center-a-wrapper-div-not-the-content)

However, it seems that this is not the optimal way to do it in HTML5, where it is preferred to use tags from a series of special new ones.

What is the best way to center a page in HTML5?

**TO BE MORE CLEAR**

From what I understand, HTML5 was created to get rid of the many `div`s found in websites and provide a standard skeleton. Instead of there being `<div id="header">` and `<div class="section">` etc, the powers-that-be determined it would be better to have standard tags. For this reason, I don't feel comfortable surrounding everything with a `<div>`. I feel like there is probably a better, more clean, HTML5-friendly way. 
Perhaps I'm wrong...

Comment: By saying best what do you mean? From what point of view?

Comment: What do you mean properly? You could use the `<main>` tag, for example. And if you give that an ID of wrapper, then your `CSS` wouldn't change..It's still the same principal that you use `CSS` to style the page regardless if it's `HTML4`/`XHTML`/`HTML5` tags being used on the page.

Comment: None of the HTML5 elements, new or old, are for the purpose of presentation effects like centering. That's what CSS is for.

Comment: Update: I made myself more clear

Comment: `margin: auto;` is still the preferred method to center an element. I disagree with `main` being an element that should be centered, see my comment on Severin's post for more info.

Comment: @Imray - To your update. There may be merit in using `<header>`, `<section>`, `<main>` etc instead of a `<div>`, but the choice of element is completely independent of whether it should be centered or not.

Answer (score 1):

Until now the way you describe is still the preferred one. Some time in the future you might use the `<main>` tag for this, but for now you are 'stuck' with the `<div> auto-margin` method.

You can read some more about the `<main>` tag here: http://html5doctor.com/the-main-element/

Comment: I still disagree with `main´ being the element that is centered. If you have a sidebar next to your content, the sidebar would go in an `aside`, the content inside `main` and *both* of them would be wrapped in a `div` which then is the `wrapper` element (`section` could also work, but that does not feel right). Main should not be the element that wraps everything, but it should be the container of the **main** content.